# Dynamic range to convert column into upper case

Tags: excel, vba, toupper

```
Sub Trim(sh,FirstCell,LastCell)
    Sheets(sh).select
    Range(FirstCell,LastCell) = [index(Upper(FirstCell,LastCell),)]
End Sub
```

I want to do something like this to make it dynamic. Calling this macro through other application where I'm giving input for sheet name first cell and last cell of the range.

Comment: What is the problem.  There is no question here.

Comment: Also you need to note if `FirstCell` and `LastCell` are ranges or strings, because that will determine the answer.

Comment: This is failing since range are declare through variable. If giving directly column name it is running successfully.

Comment: Currently using it like this 
Sub Trim_columnV(sh)
    Sheets(sh).select
 Range("V:V") = [index(Trim(V:V),)]
End Sub

Comment: May I recommend reading [the documentation for the `UPPER` function?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/upper-function-c11f29b3-d1a3-4537-8df6-04d0049963d6)  (And/or [the VBA equivalent `UCase` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ucase-function)?)  Neither of them accept 2 arguments.

Comment: That is calling Trim_columnV not Trim - how are you defining FirstCell and LastCell in your call - they are actually variants because you have not included a type

Comment: Please don't use `Trim` as the name of your subroutine; that shadows the [`Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions) function.

Answer (score 2):

One cannot use `[]` with variables it expects a string.  Also ranges already have the Sheet in the variable and adding it is not needed:

```
Sub MyTrim(rng as Range)    
    rng.value = rng.Parent.Evaluate("index(Upper(" & rng.adress & "),)")
End Sub
```

Or use UCase:

```
Sub MyTrim(rng as Range)
    If rng.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        rng = UCase(rng)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim RngArray() as Variant
    RngArray = rng

    Dim i as Long
    For i = 1 to Ubound(RngArray,1)
        Dim j as Long
        For j = 1 to Ubound(RngArray, 2)
            RngArray(i,j) = UCase(RngArray(i,j))
        Next j
    Next i
    rng = rngarray
End Sub
```

Comment: getting an exception for the first solution given 
Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)) 

my input : {"A:A"}

Comment: You would put `Worksheet("blah").Range("A:A")` you need to pass a range not a string.  Change `Blah` to the worksheet name.

Answer (score 2):

### Upper-Case a Column Using `Evaluate`

```
Sub UCaseColumnTEST()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    UCaseColumn ws, "A1", "A20"
End Sub

Sub UCaseColumn( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal FirstCellAddress As String, _
        ByVal LastCellAddress As String)
    With ws.Range(FirstCellAddress, LastCellAddress)
        .Value = ws.Evaluate("UPPER(" & .Address & ")")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: getting an exception 
 Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))

my input : {"datasheet","A","A"}

Comment: For the workbook containing this code, `ThisWorkbook`, you could use something like the following one-liner: `UCaseColumn ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet"), "A1", "A10"`.